# Combine two promises while maintaining execution order and flow of data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have two promises 
promise1 , resolves to a array of objects
promise2, creates  multiple files and then writes to them resolves to boolean value of whether it was successful or not using the array from promise1.

the execution is as follows:
1.on resolving the first promise I get the array of objects say arr1.
2.Inside the then() of promise1 I proceed to create a array of promises based on the array of objects arr1 where each promise resolves the success of file write.

Now, I would like to return a promise after combining both that resolves to a boolean value..

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: If you could post your code, we could post a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` for the first one (if you're comfortable), f.e:

`const magicArray = await magicHappens();`

and then, if you want, you can use the mentioned `Promise.all([]);` or if you have lots of promises, use `async.mapLimit()`

Comment: I don't think `async.mapLimit` does work with promises.

Comment: But you can resolve promises by mapping all the array of values which will be awaited and returning the results

Answer (score -1):

> Inside the then() of promise1 I proceed to create a array of promises

Just use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on that array and `return` the resulting promise from your `then` callback.

The `then()` call will then return a promise for the array of boolean results (from each file), onto which you can chain another `then` callback that combines these into a single boolean value.

Comment: Assuming each process resolves with successful write then the returned array of `true` values might be treated as truthy. However if any one of them fails then `Promise.all` will reject and we may catch it and return a Promise.resolve(false) at the `catch` stage.

Comment: @Redu Yes. OP said that his write function returns a promise that always fulfills with a boolean, `false` when failed, so I didn't consider any rejections.